# Why do letters on a PCB not match those on the back side?

Tags: pcb

This is a typical PCB from ebay, front and back side:

[image: PCB front and back]

The sides are identical, and not mirrored. Which is funny because the `A` row on the front is the `X` row on the back.

Is there a logical/practical reason to this, or is it just convenient for the manufacturer to print only one layout instead of mirroring the letters on the other side? I would find it much more useful if the letters were mirrored and could be used to uniquely identify a hole, no matter which side I am looking at the PCB from.

Comment: I would say it is not a question to *manufacturer*, but rather to PCB designer - the person or entity producing Gerber files. I agree with @Trevor you need to ensure that flipping board around the same edge you see A on pad at one side and X on the same pad on another side, it is not clear from your picture (and from your explanation).

Comment: The manufacturer hired an inexperienced PCB designer who did not pay attention to this detail.

Comment: Can you show the whole board btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got what you paid for. Rock bottom quality at rock bottom prices. It's typical of cost cutting manufacturing.

Comment: In what way does producing a PCB in this manner "cut costs"? Is it that much cheaper to duplicate the print on the reverse of each unit rather than having a second, pseudo-mirrored print?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I presume it would be, tooling is one of the larger costs of PCB manufacture - one set of silk screen stencils. Probably even only one set of masks for copper, solder mask and silkscreen. Use the same masks for top and bottom sides.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: I see!

Answer (score 3):

There's no logic, practical or convenient reason for this. If what you write is true, it is not a *typical* PCB. It's a flawed PCB; someone made a mistake.

Comment: Or just stereotypical Chinese engineering.

Comment: It is in fact from China. (Updated my question.)

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster It doesn't have to be from China to have a mistake. I once swapped the letters next to a pin header on a board I made. However, I never tried to sell them..

Answer (score 0):

Which side is the "FRONT" ?

Arguably it does not have a front till you put something on it... at which point the labels on the back become meaningless.

Still not too handy though.

Comment: Not really. Put item a in hole a1 and a3. Now solder a1 and a3 on the back. Item a falls out. Instructions unclear. Because of the mismatched labels.

Comment: @Passerby, yes I understand, and agree with you. But figured it was worth a mention.